# jQuery not running, no error message. Syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good morning,

jsbin attached: http://jsbin.com/kasofufuni/edit?html,css,js,console,output

I'm trying to make a simple show/hide function. I've pared it down to what you can see in the code above, but some sort of syntax error is causing it to not run or give an error. I've been mashing at it for a couple hours. Any ideas?

I got it to work once in a console, but I have not been able to reproduce.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav#global').prepend('<span id="menu-icon">Menu</span> <span id="search-icon">Search</span>');

 });   

$('#menu-icon').on('click',function(){
    $('nav#global').prepend('You clicked it'); 
});
```

Comment: Please add code to this page and not external sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event code is outside of *document.ready* so it runs before element exists

Change to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('nav#global').prepend('<span id="menu-icon">Menu</span> <span id="search-icon">Search</span>');  


    $('#menu-icon').on('click',function(){
        $('nav#global').prepend('You clicked it'); 
    });

 });
```

Code will run fine in console because element exists then

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include the code in your `document.ready` function, you can use some event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu-icon', function(){
    $('nav#global').prepend('You clicked it'); 
});
```